# Omnet++ and INET for 802154a

Tags: c++, simulation, omnet++, nic, inet

I am trying to implement what was available on MiXiM framework using INET 3.4.0, i.e. the protocol 802.15.4a (UWB).

INET offers already the *NIC* module (radio+MAC) but not the rest, i.e the network and application layer.

I would like to create a 'dummy' simulations where two 802154a hosts send and receive messages using the *INET NIC* module called *Ieee802154UWBIRNic*.

I tried to follow the implementation used by MiXiM but I got lost with all the Base modules etc etc.

Can someone help me?
I also implemented a simple network layer and then tried to use *PingApp* but it is not working, it says something like

```
'Host Address Unknown'
```

Answer (score 1):

My university colleage did some work with IEEE 802.15.4
in OMNeT++ with INET Framework : "A New IEEE 802.15.4 Simulation Model
for OMNeT++ / INET" https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1177.pdf

Problem here is we're just porting it for newer INET Version and OMNeT++ but sooner or later it will work.
It should be possible to use it for OMNeT++ 4.6 with INET 2.6 there is some implementation working for all the stuff you mentioned.